# Как сделать лимит времени на запросы для пользователя в Telegram боте Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, limit

У меня есть код, для обработки сообщения. Мне нужно чтобы после отправки первого сообщения от бота, начался таймер на 10 минут, по завершению которого пользователь снова сможет получить сообщение от бота. А если таймер не закончится, вывести сообщение: "Ты можешь получать сообщения только раз в 10 минут". Я пытался сделать это через datatime(), но проблема в том что он не изменяет переменную delta и код не работает.

```
delta = 0

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def get_text(message):

    if message.text == 'КОЭФИЦЕНТ' and datetime.now().minute - delta > 10:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Сообщение', reply_markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        delta = datetime.now().minute
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Сообщение можно отправлять только раз в 10 минут')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте `global delta` в начало функции, чтобы интерпретатор понимал, что нужно изменять глобальную переменную, а не создавать локальную внутри функции

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def get_text(message):
    global delta
```